# React. Как оптимизировать функцию

Tags: reactjs

У меня есть несколько селектов (их больше, но тут показал только два)

```js
<div className='wrapper'>
            <form>
                <label>
                    <p className="nameOfInput">Vendor</p>
                    <select onChange={props.filterOurData} >
                        <option>Choose vendor</option>
                        {unique.map((element) => <option  key={element.toString()}>{element}</option>)}
                    </select>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <p className="nameOfInput">Location</p>
                    <select onChange={props.filterOurLocation} >
                        <option>Choose location</option>
                        {unique2.map((element) => <option key=  {element.toString()}>{element}</option>)}
                    </select>
                </label>

            </form>
        </div>
```

Для каждого селекта выполняется несколько строк кода. В этих строках я перебираю и фильтрую props.data.nodes. Получаю массивы unique, unique2 и каждый массив использую в своем селекте. Эти строки кода отличаются только одним значением. Хочу написать функцию, которая заменит эти фактически дублирующиеся строки кода. 
В целом всё работает, ошибок нет, но нужна оптимизация кода.

```js
    let arr = props.data.nodes.map((element) => element.vendor);
    let unique = arr.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
        return index === self.indexOf(elem);
    });   //  выбираю нужные значения и подставляю их в первый селект
    
    let arr2 = props.data.nodes.map((element) => element.location);
    let unique2 = arr2.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
        return index === self.indexOf(elem);
    });   // выбираю нужные значения и подставляю их во второй селект
```

Ниже написал, какую универсальную функцию я хочу получить. Данная функция показана, как пример, она не работает. Данная функция должна выполняться для каждого селекта, должна получать от каждого свое уникальное значение и на выходе выдавать соответствующий массив для каждого селекта. После этого каждый селект использует свой массив и рендерится на странице. 
А как переписать правильно - не могу сообразить..

```
const func = (myData) => {
    let arr = props.data.nodes.map((element) => element.myData);
    let unique = arr.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
        return index === self.indexOf(elem);
    });
```

}

всё приложение целиком: https://github.com/DrGreenNow/Relate-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const getUniqueKeys = (arr, key) => (
  arr
    .map(el => el[key])
    .filter((el, i, self) => i === self.indexOf(el))
);

/* функция выше является ответом */

class Form extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { data, filterOurData, filterOurLocation, filterOurService, filterOurDeviceType } = this.props;

    /* пример использования */
    const vendors = getUniqueKeys(data.nodes, "vendor");
    const locations = getUniqueKeys(data.nodes, "location");
    const services = getUniqueKeys(data.nodes, "service");
    const types = getUniqueKeys(data.nodes, "type");
    
    return(
        <div className='wrapper'>
            <form>
                <label>
                    <p className="nameOfInput">Vendor</p>
                    <select onChange={filterOurData} >
                        <option>Choose vendor</option>
                        {vendors.map((element) => <option  key={element.toString()}>{element}</option>)}
                    </select>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <p className="nameOfInput">Location</p>
                    <select onChange={filterOurLocation} >
                        <option>Choose location</option>
                        {locations.map((element) => <option key={element.toString()}>{element}</option>)}
                    </select>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <p className="nameOfInput">Service</p>
                    <select onChange={filterOurService} >
                        <option>Choose service</option>
                        {services.map((element) => <option key={element.toString()}>{element}</option>)}
                    </select>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <p className="nameOfInput">Device Type</p>
                    <select onChange={filterOurDeviceType} >
                        <option>Choose device type</option>
                        {types.map((element) => <option key={element.toString()}>{element}</option>)}
                    </select>
                </label>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
  }    
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: null
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DrGreenNow/Relate-data/master/src/NavigationTree.json`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ data }))
      .catch(console.error)
  }
  
  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return data && <Form data={data} />
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
form {
  margin: 30px 30px 30px 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

select {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.nameOfInput {
  width: 200px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```